# Is GET value empty?

Tags: php

I've checked this site for this an the solution is:

```
empty($_GET)
```

But when I var dump this it is:

```
false
```

How can this be? I've dumped it before my the rest of my code and died the page.

Am I checking it's value wrong?

Comment: what does print_r($_GET) say

Comment: Are you not using a conditional `if`? I.e.: `if(empty($_GET)){...}`

Comment: *"But how is it not empty, nothing else is happening on my page"* - Show your full code then; we read code, not minds.

Comment: Show an empty page? Why

Comment: What do you mean by: "I've dumped it before my the rest of my code"?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for:

```
count($_GET)
```

if it's zero then any param has been received.